# How to optimize php nested foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach, nested-loops

I'm trying to connect two product API and what i chose was saving each product list and then nest them in a foreach loop.But the problem is that number of products are growing over time and nested foreach loops takes too long time to work or times out on server. Is there any alternative or solution other than nesting foreach loops on how I make it optimized and run faster?
Consider having only 100 products and then calculate how long it takes to run updating.

Here is a brief for my code:

```
        $webServiceProducts = $this->webserviceGetData('GetAllData',$webserviceProductBody);
        $websiteProducts = $this->wooGetReq('products');
        $updateCounter = 0;
        foreach ($webServiceProducts as $keyM => $valueM) {
            foreach ($websiteProducts as $keyW => $valueW){
                if($valueM->ProductId == $valueW->sku){
                    $updateCounter++;
                    $sendProductData = [
                      'name'=>$valueM->Name,
                      'sku'=>strval($valueM->ProductId),
                    ];
                    $theCurrentWebsiteProductId = $valueW->id;
                    $updateAllProducts = $this->wooPutReq('products/'.strval($theCurrentWebsiteProductId) ,$sendProductData );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        echo $updateCounter.' Items Updated';
```

Comment: We cant write you an answer that is not an opinion. here is one,  unset the products that you found in `$websiteProducts` so the next iteration dont loop it again. Here is another one, develop a bulk `wooPutReq` and adapt your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're checking every product in one list against ever product in the other, which means if each list contains 100 items you're doing 10,000 comparisons and that that number will increase exponentially as items are added to either list.

It looks like you're simply matching an ID in one list to a SKU in the other, so  [assuming that there are no duplicate values within the lists themselves] if you sort each list by those ID values you can simply walk over the lists in linear time with something like the following:

```php
$products_a = [1, 3, 5, 8, 12, 13];
$products_b = [1, 2, 4, 5, 12, 15];

$ac = count($products_a);
$bc = count($products_b);

$matches = [];
$comparisons = 0;

for($a=0, $b=0; $a<$ac && $b<$bc; ) {
    $cmp = $products_a[$a] - $products_b[$b];
    ++$comparisons;
    
    if( $cmp == 0 ) {
        $matches[] = $products_a[$a];
        ++$a;
        ++$b;
    } else if ( $cmp > 0 ) {
        ++$b;
    } else {
        ++$a;
    }
}

printf("Matches: %s\nComparisons: %d\n", json_encode($matches), $comparisons);
```

Output:

```
Matches: [1,5,12]
Comparisons: 8
```

Your existing method would have done 36 comparisons for the example lists, so at  just 8 you can already see a significant time savings.